# Why does my OneToOne mapping through a JoinTable not work?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I've searched but cannot seem to find the answer.

I have two tables:

```
select ts_id, tsjoin_id, workdate from TimeSheets
select e_id, lastname from Employees
```

I also have a join table:

```
TSJoin
tsjoin_id, employee_id
```

There is only one Employee to a TimeSheet.  So with any given TimeSheet entity, I'd expect to be able to:

```
TimeSheet ts = tsService.getTimeSheet(123);
String lastName = ts.getEmployee().getLastName();
```

In SQL, to get the employee of a TimeSheet:

```
select e.lastname from TimeSheets t
    join TSJoin x on (x.tsjoin_id = t.tsjoin_id)
    join Employees e on (e.e_id = x.employee_id)
where t.ts_id = 123
```

In my `Hibernate` mapping, I have:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinTable(
        name = "TSJoin",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "tsjoin_id", nullable = false)
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "e_id", nullable = false)
        }
)
```

However, the SQL it's generating is:

```
select * from TimeSheet t
    left outer join TSJoin x on (t.ts_id = x.tsjoin_id)
```

Which returns null for the Employee.

It's taking the primary key of the TimeSheet and trying to match the primary key of the join table.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I also want to state that I have only setup one direction at this point.  Which is a `TimeSheet -> Employee` (OneToOne) and that `Employee` is not mapped to `TimeSheet` **yet**.  Not sure if this makes a difference but I wanted to mention it.

**EDIT 2**
I also want to state that I believe the error might be because my join table does not contain a reference to the `TimeSheet`.  And Hibernate is assuming that a join table is going to contain the primary keys of each entity involved (legacy database).  I could probably create a mapping of `TimeSheet` -> `JoinTable` -> `Employee` and access it as: `ts.getJoin().getEmployee()` but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: I tried it and basically it should work. I am getting two select statements:

`select timesheet0_.id as id1_14_, timesheet0_.workdate as workdate2_14_, timesheet0_1_.e_id as e_id1_13_ from Timesheet timesheet0_ left outer join TSJoin timesheet0_1_ on timesheet0_.id=timesheet0_1_.tsjoin_id`
And directly after that:
`select employee0_.id as id1_5_0_, employee0_.lastname as lastname2_5_0_ from Employee employee0_ where employee0_.id=?`
So in your case, the second query is missing. I have only tried with a unidirectional one-to-one association from Timesheet to Employee...

Comment: Right now, I just have the one mapping.  TimeSheet -> Employee.   I thought once that was working, I would try the other way.  Which would be a OneToMany  (Employee -> TimeSheetS).  Do I need to have both directions defined for either to work?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you fetch the timesheet in your service method `tsService.getTimesheet`?

Comment: Right now I'm just using `Spring Data JPA` and literally using "findAll".  I get a long list of TimeSheets but of course the Employee is null on each one.

Comment: Hmhm..have you tried to fetch the Employee eagerly? Just to see if that helps..?

Comment: Yep.   In fact, I left that out of my original post but I've tried both ways.

Comment: Sry, no idea anymore:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost 100% sure this problem is because the current JPA spec does not allow a non primary key column in the JoinTable.  Our legacy database joins to columns that are not primary keys.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a join table is assumed to containg the ID of the two joined entities.

In your case, it doesn't: the ID of the TimeSheet entity is mapped to the `ts_id` column, but you want the join table to have a column which is a foreign key to the `tsjoin_id` column instead of `ts_id`.

So you need to tell that to Hibernate. It can't guess it. And the [javadoc of JoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName%28%29) says:

> referencedColumnName
>
> (Optional) The name of the column referenced by this foreign key column. [...]
>
> Default (only applies if single join column is being used): The same name as the primary key column of the referenced table.

So all you need is

```
@JoinTable(
    name = "TSJoin",
    joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "tsjoin_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "tsjoin_id")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "e_id", nullable = false)
    }
)
```

Note that having one employee per timesheet isn't sufficient to make your association a OneToOne. To be a OneToOne, there should also be one timesheet per employee. If an emplyee has, in fact, several timesheets, tha association is a ManyToOne, not a OneToOne.

Comment: Thanks, but I've actually tried that already.  I get:   org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: tsjoin_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(TimeSheet)

Comment: Have you mapped this column to a field in the TimeSheet entity? You need to.

Comment: Yeah.  And when I do that I get:  SecondaryTable JoinColumn cannot reference a non primary key.

Comment: Then it probably can't be done. Sorry. I must confess I'm not used to dealing with such messy schemas. Why don't you make things simple and simply add a foreign key in TimeSheet to the PK of Employee?

Comment: Database is legacy and cannot be changed.  I believe this is a limitation of JPA/Hibernate.  I guess I will go back to creating views.